# Fisher ideal index

Tags: statistics

Fisher's ideal output index for two consecutive Years 0 and 1 is defined as

$\sqrt{(\sum\frac{p_0Q_1}{p_0Q_0})(\sum\frac{p_1Q_1}{p_1Q_0})}$

Is there a purely mathematical explanataion as to why Fisher chose to take the geometric mean of the two RGDP ratios. Why not, say, take the arithmetic mean?

Comment: Please provide some more background. Where does this come from? What are the symbols?  And is Fisher's original paper silent on why he chose this form?

Comment: $(\sum\frac{p_0Q_1}{p_0Q_0})$ is GDP in Year 1 valued at Year 0 prices relative to GDP in Year 0 relative to Year 0 prices. The same goes for the other factor, just with Year 1 prices

Comment: Interestingly, the Fischer ideal index is not the only way to combine Paasche's and Laspeyre's indexes. The Sigdwick-Drobish averages them (with the arithmetic mean) as you propose. Probably, the question could be equivalently worded as why the Sigdwick-Drobish index is a lot less known and used than the Fisher ideal index.

Answer (score 1):

The Laspeyres index and the Paasche index are both indices for the growth of the prices. And if **growth rates** are involved then you have to use the geometric mean to calculate the average growth rate.

Example:

Laspeyres index=$1.2$ and Paasche index=$0.96$

Then the average growth rate is $\sqrt{1.2\cdot 0.96}\approx 1.07331$

The approximation sign shows only that it is an irrational number. One remark: The number of the indices are not growth rates in the meaning of economics/math. I would call them growth factors. To get the growth rates 1 has to be subtracted. For instance the average growth rate is $0.07331\approx 7.33\%$. Also note that $0.96$ means that the prices have decreased by $4\%$ (deflation).

But you need the growth factors ($1.2,0.96$) to calclate the average growth factor/rate.